# scroll to a position in the Mainadaptor then scroll to a position in the Childadaptor

Tags: android-recyclerview, scroll, position, adaptor

i have two adaptors the Childadaptor inside Mainadapter  i want to scroll to a position in the Mainadaptor then scroll to a position in the Childadaptor in android studio java i have 120000 of Childadaptor in Mainadaptor and  i have 100 textview in each Childadaptor how can i make it..

my QuranMainAdapter

```
public class QuranMainAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<QuranMainAdapter.ViewMainHolder>{
    Context context;
    ArrayList<QuranClass> textClasses;
    private final ScaleGestureDetector scaleGestureDetector;
    private float initialTextSize;
    private float textSize;
    SharedPreferences preferences;
    SharedPreferences preferencesPos;

    public QuranMainAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<QuranClass> textClasses ) {

        this.context =context;
        this.textClasses = textClasses;
        preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("size",MODE_PRIVATE);
        preferencesPos = context.getSharedPreferences("quran",MODE_PRIVATE);
        textSize = preferences.getFloat("size",35.0f);
        scaleGestureDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleGestureListener());

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewMainHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View singleRow = LayoutInflater.from(context)
                .inflate(R.layout.quraan_recycler_item, parent, false);

        return new ViewMainHolder(singleRow);


    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewMainHolder holder, int i) {
        QuranClass dataList = textClasses.get(i);
        String sureName = dataList.getName();
        String qty = dataList.getType();
        Intent intent = new Intent("custom-message");
        intent.putExtra("surahName",sureName);
        intent.putExtra("surahType",qty);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intent);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context);
        holder.recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        QuranChildAdapter childAdapter = new QuranChildAdapter(context,dataList.getAya());
        childAdapter.setTextSize(textSize);
        holder.recyclerView.setAdapter(childAdapter);

        int po = preferencesPos.getInt("positionChild",0);
        int firstPo = preferencesPos.getInt("position",0);

        if (firstPo == i){
            holder.recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(po);
        }



        holder.recyclerView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                preferencesPos.edit().putInt("position",i).apply();
                if (event.getPointerCount()==2){
                    scaleGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
                }
                return true;
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if (textClasses ==null){
            return 0;
        }else {
            return textClasses.size();
        }
    }


   public static class ViewMainHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{


        RecyclerView recyclerView;
        public ViewMainHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            recyclerView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.quran_item_rec);

        }
    }

    public void setTextSize(float textSize) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putFloat("size", textSize);
        editor.apply();
        this.textSize =textSize;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    private class ScaleGestureListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            // Calculate the scale factor from the gesture detector
            float scaleFactor = detector.getScaleFactor();

            // Calculate the new text size based on the initial text size and the scale factor
            float newTextSize = initialTextSize * scaleFactor;

            // Apply the new text size to the child adapter
            setTextSize(newTextSize);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onScaleBegin(@NonNull ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            // Set the initial text size
            initialTextSize = textSize;
            return true;
        }
    }

}
```

my QuranChildAdapter that i need to scroll after QuranMainAdapter finish scrolling.

```
public class QuranChildAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
    private final List<Verse> childItemList;
    Context context;
    private float textSize;

    public QuranChildAdapter(Context context, List<Verse> childItemList) {
        this.childItemList = childItemList;
        this.context =context;
        this.textSize = 35.0f; // Default text size



    }


    @NotNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {

        switch (i) {
            case 0:
                return new Header_guran(LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.quraan_header_item, viewGroup, false));
            case 1:
                return new base_quran(LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.quraan_basm_item, viewGroup, false));
            case 2:
                View  itemView =LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.quraan_surha_item,
                        viewGroup, false);
                return new main_quran(itemView);
            default:
                return new footer_quran(LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.quraan_footer_item, viewGroup, false));

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder myHolder, int ii) {
        Verse dataList = childItemList.get(ii);

        switch (myHolder.getItemViewType()) {
            case 0:
                ((Header_guran) myHolder).header_lie.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                ((Header_guran) myHolder).header.setText(dataList.getSurahName());
                break;
            case 1:
                ((base_quran) myHolder).basm.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, textSize);
                ((base_quran) myHolder).basm.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                break;

            case 2:
                SpannableStringBuilder pages;
               pages = new SpannableStringBuilder();

                    String end = "<font color='#63824E'>" + "\u06DD" + dataList.getAyahNumberInSurah() + "</font>";
                    String ayahSpannable = dataList.getSurahAyahText();
                    Spanned endSpannable = HtmlCompat.fromHtml(end, 0);
                    Typeface ayahFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "font/amiri_quran.ttf");
                    pages.append(ayahSpannable)
                            .append(endSpannable);
                ((main_quran) myHolder).textView.setTypeface(ayahFont);
                ((main_quran) myHolder).textView.setText(pages);
                ((main_quran) myHolder).textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, textSize);
                int i = ii;
                ((main_quran) myHolder).textView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                    SharedPreferences preferencesChild;
                    @Override
                    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
                        preferencesChild =context.getSharedPreferences("quran",MODE_PRIVATE);
                        preferencesChild.edit().putInt("positionChild",i).apply();
                        switch (event.getAction()) {
                            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                                ((main_quran) myHolder).textView.setShadowLayer(1, 0, 0, Color.BLACK);
                                break;
                            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                                ((main_quran) myHolder).textView.setShadowLayer(0, 0, 0, Color.TRANSPARENT);
                                break;
                            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                                ((main_quran) myHolder).textView.setShadowLayer(0, 0, 0, Color.TRANSPARENT);
                                break;

                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                });
                break;
            default:
                ((footer_quran) myHolder).footer.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, textSize);;
                ((footer_quran) myHolder).footer.setText(String.format("-﴿ %s ﴾-", dataList.getPage()));
                break;
        }



    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if (childItemList ==null){
            return 0;
        }else {
            return childItemList.size();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        Verse dataList = childItemList.get(position);
        String type = dataList.getTypeView();
        if ("header".equals(type)) {
            return 0;
        } else if ("bismillah".equals(type)) {
            return 1;
        } else if ("verse".equals(type)) {
            return 2;
        } else {
            return 3;
        }
    }


    public  class Header_guran extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView header;
        LinearLayout header_lie;

        public Header_guran(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            header = itemView.findViewById(R.id.sure_name_header);
            header_lie = itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_header_quran);
        }

    }
    public  class base_quran extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView basm;
        public base_quran(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            basm = itemView.findViewById(R.id.basm_name_header);
        }
    }
    public  class main_quran extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        QuranTextView textView;
        public main_quran(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_quran);

        }
    }
    public  class footer_quran extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView footer;
        public footer_quran(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            footer = itemView.findViewById(R.id.page_footer);
        }
    }





    public void setTextSize(float textSize) {
        this.textSize = textSize;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
```

my activity

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_quraan);
        juse = findViewById(R.id.jouse);
        suraName = findViewById(R.id.sure_name);
        preferencesAct = getSharedPreferences("quran",MODE_PRIVATE);
        int po = preferencesAct.getInt("position",0);
        recyclerView =findViewById(R.id.quran_rec);
        database = new QuraanDatabase(this);
        objDbModelClassArrayList =new ArrayList<>();
        objDbModelClassArrayList = database.getAllPages();
        objDbAdapter  = new QuranMainAdapter(this,objDbModelClassArrayList);
        mLayoutManager = new AdjustLinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(objDbAdapter );
        mLayoutManager.setScrollType(mScrollType);
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this, DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL));
        mLayoutManager.setMillisecondsPerInch(10f);
        mLayoutManager.smoothScrollToPosition(recyclerView,null,po);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).
                registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver, new IntentFilter("custom-message"));
        suraName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SurahQuranMain customerDialog = new SurahQuranMain();
                customerDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "Surah Quran Main");
            }
        });

    }
```

i have two adaptors the Childadaptor inside Mainadapter  i want to scroll to a position in the Mainadaptor then scroll to a position in the Childadaptor in android studio java i have 120000 of Childadaptor in Mainadaptor and  i have 100 textview in each Childadaptor i want exmple for adaptors also